# Incognito mode browser, angularjs updates only when mouse enters window

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting a wired behavior with my angular app.

When I open my app in a few incognito windows, and one window gets update, I expect that also other windows will get update with their angular views, however only when I enter the window with my mouse it gets updated. any idea why I'm getting this behavior?

Comment: You'll need to tell us more about your localhost server - are you using a form of LiveReload or BrowserSync?

Comment: No, I'm not using live reload. And my backend is nodejs